# How to download sql server driver using azure dev ops/ pipelines

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, pyodbc

I am connecting to SQL server using the library pyodbc. I downloaded the driver locally using the following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16. All my code now works and I want to run it on azure. Is there an azure pipeline task to download the same driver am using locally? do I include it in a script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use [**Microsoft-hosted agents**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) to run the pipeline, normally you do not need an extra step to install the ODBC Driver:

- On **`windows-2022`** (**`windows-latest`**) agent, it has the component "**Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.MSODBC.SQL v17.2.32408.312**" installed.
- On **`windows-2019`** agent, it has the component "**Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.MSODBC.SQL v16.0.28625.61**" installed.

If you use [self-hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops) which installed on your local machine or VM, you can login to the machine, then manually download and install the required ODBC Driver version.

Comment: is there an equivalent for ubuntu agent? or do I have to use windows-latest?

Answer (score -1):

Are you planning to run on a hosted agent? If so it should already have the sql server ODBC driver installed. You can confirm this by configuring a new pipeline on a hosted agent and running the following in a powershell task

```
Get-OdbcDriver
```